# Python Slicing Issue: every other element in list, starting with last element not working?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, slice

so I have a list of numbers, and I want to start at the last element of the list and print every other element.

So given list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] I would print 6, 4 and 2. My issue is that slicing is not printing the last element.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in list[-1::-2]:
    print(list[i])
```

this merely prints 4 and 2, showing me that the last digit is not included. I have also tried omitting the -1 and just using list[::-2]. It takes every odd digit (4 and 2) but does not include 6. I want to use slicing to achieve this result, but clearly I am misunderstanding how to use it. Any help much appreciated (this is my first stackOverflow question btw!)

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid using the variable names as a list.

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in ls[-1::-2]:
    print(i)
```

You're iterating all the elements of the list using the `in` method. It doesn't provide you an index that you will use to print.

When you're trying to print `list[i]` it will raise an error because when `i=6` then `list[i]` element don't exist in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing just `i` instead of the `list[i]`?
You should remember here that if you iterate through a reversed list, you need not do indexing again. The `i` would hold the value of the list element.

Please try:

```
for i in ls[::-2]:
     print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do slicing by using:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(ls[-1::-2])
```

and don't use the `list` as a variable name because it is a keyword in Python so you will get an error.